# Jersey has written my mysql timestamp as 2011-09-28T21:48:25Z how do I format it in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, xml, date, jersey

I have a mysql backend that has a timestamp field that is auto set as currenttimestamp like so (`date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP). After reading the value as Date, [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net) sends out an xml where the timestamp shows as

```
<timestamp>2011-09-28T21:48:25Z</timestamp>
```

Please don't make too much of the backstory: I can't change what I get from Jersey. Now my question is this: how do I parse the 2011-09-28T21:48:25Z from xml as a date that Java understands?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") ;
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Zulu")) ;
Date dd = df.parse("2011-09-28T21:48:25Z") ;
```

...then, optionally,

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(dd.getTime()) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2011-09-28T21:48:25Z" )
```

## ISO 8601

Your input string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

[Jersey](https://jersey.java.net) is irrelevant, except that its designers wisely chose to use ISO 8601 formats for serializing date-time values as strings.

## java.time

The java.time classes built into Java use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating Strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

## UTC

The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (GMT).

## `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2011-09-28T21:48:25Z" );
```

## Time Zone

Adjust that `Instant` into any time zone you desire.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name). Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );  // Or "Asia/Kolkata" etc.
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

## Strings

Do not conflate date-time values with Strings that represent such values.

You can ask the java.time objects to generate a String in any format you desire. But generally best to let the `DateTimeFormatter` automatically localize for you.

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;  // Or Locale.US, Locale.ITALY, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( l );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```