# Parsing ISO-8601 DateTime with offset with colon in Java

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-parsing

I have a trouble with parsing date time in java, I have a strange date time format.
How can I parse `2013-04-03T17:04:39.9430000+03:00` date time in java to format `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm` in java?

Comment: You *parse* from text to non-text. You *format* from non-text to text. It sounds like you need two `SimpleDateFormat` objects - one to parse, and the other to format. Try this, and edit your question with your attempt if you don't succeed.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7604237/642706

Comment: FYI, that input string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Comment: @BasilBourque thank you for your response, "drewmoore" also stated below which format that date is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "strange" format in question is [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) - its very widely used. You can use [SimpleDateFormat](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html&ei=2E2CUdrjKsKWiALwqIDQBQ&usg=AFQjCNFpk4Rdc3mSC_t_-Uk-RgEzbY1HFQ&sig2=hNLhpx22PyHZGhWAwxPeUA&bvm=bv.45960087,d.cGE) to reformat it in most way you please:

```
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
DateTime dtIn = inFormat.parse(dateString});  //where dateString is a date in ISO-8601 format
SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
String dtOut = outFormat.format(dtIn);
//parse it into a DateTime object if you need to interact with it as such
```

will give you the format you mentioned.

Comment: It's strange that (Simple)DateFormat doesn't come with a standard option for the widely-used ISO-8601 format, instead requiring developers to roll their own format string. Maybe it's because ISO-8601 can have so many different variations.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: This Answer fails to address the microseconds/nanoseconds in the Question.

Answer (score 11):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2013-04-03T17:04:39.9430000+03:00" ).format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm" ) )
```

## ISO 8601

As the others noted, your format is not strange at all. Indeed it is a standard format. That format is one of a collection defined by the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

## Microseconds

Those seven digits of a decimal fraction of a second, `.9430000`, represents [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). The old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java (java.util.Date/.Calendar/java.text.SimpleDateFormat) are built only for [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) (three digits of decimal fraction). Such input values as your cannot be handled by the old classes.

## java.time

Fortunately Java now has newer date-time classes that supplant those old classes. The new ones are in the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. These new classes can handle nanoseconds (up to nine digits of decimal fraction), so no problem there.

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and later. Defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Much of the functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and further adapted for Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

### `OffsetDateTime`

An `OffsetDateTime` represents a moment on the timeline with an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). Your input string, `2013-04-03T17:04:39.9430000+03:00`, has an offset that is three hours ahead of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to define a formatting pattern. We can directly parse that string.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2013-04-03T17:04:39.9430000+03:00" );
```

### Generating Strings

To generate a string representation in the same style, call its [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toString--) method.

For a different format define a formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm" );
String output = odt.format( formatter );
```

## Time Zone

Note that your input has an offset-from-UTC but not a true time zone. A time zone is an offset *plus* rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). For a true time zone use `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Search Stack Overflow for many examples.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: What are the imports for `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`? Android Studio can't find them.

Comment: @MatthewDrill See last bulleted items, just added now.

Answer (score 0):

For serious work with date and time in java I would suggest using a better implementation than the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) stuff. I would use [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), and therein you can use [DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: Is my answer so bad to make a downvote? any comment from the downvoter on that? Maybe I can improve. I really think that Joda time has many advantages over the standard java date/time implementation.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, and I love JodaTime and use it frequently, but it isn't necessary for what the OP wanted to do, and thus wasn't really a relevant answer to the question.

Comment: You did not really answer OPs question. He could be in a situation where it is not possible for him to add an external library to his project. I am not the downvoter, this is just my take on it. Your answer is still correct though, just not 100% an answer to OP.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please use this method for parse ISO8601 Date without any library.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/ISO8601dateparsingutility.htm

```
public static Date parseISO8601Date(String input ) throws java.text.ParseException {

    //NOTE: SimpleDateFormat uses GMT[-+]hh:mm for the TZ which breaks
    //things a bit.  Before we go on we have to repair this.
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz" );

    //this is zero time so we need to add that TZ indicator for
    if ( input.endsWith( "Z" ) ) {
        input = input.substring( 0, input.length() - 1) + "GMT-00:00";
    } else {
        int inset = 6;

        String s0 = input.substring( 0, input.length() - inset );
        String s1 = input.substring( input.length() - inset, input.length() );

        input = s0 + "GMT" + s1;
    }

    return df.parse( input );

}
```