# Java parse string as date "2017-06-12T14:45:00+05:30"

Tags: java, string, date, parsing

How do I parse this String in Java as date
"2017-06-12T14:45:00+05:30"
I've tried using SimpleDateFormat but it is throwing exception.
Thanks

Comment: What java version you're using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing ISO-8601 DateTime in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336643/parsing-iso-8601-datetime-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a valid ISO offset date time format, so this should work without requiring a formatter:

```
OffsetDateTime date = OffsetDateTime.parse(input);
```

If you really need a `java.util.Date`, you can then use:

```
Date legacyDate = Date.from(date.toInstant());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(string);
```

date is your solution

Comment: No it says Unparseable date: "2017-06-12T14:45:00+05:30"

Comment: I recommend you stay away from the long outdated classes like `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. The modern classes lke `OffsetDateTime` are so much more programmer friendly. An added bonus is the mentioned class parses the ISO 8601 string from the question out of the box with no explicit format.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide correct pattern in SimpleDateForamt

```
    String startDateString = "09/23/2009";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
Date startDate;
try {
    startDate = df.parse(startDateString);
    String newDateString = df.format(startDate);
    System.out.println(newDateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: want to parse "2017-06-12T14:45:00+05:30"

Comment: try pattern like new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);